# Importing Python classes

Tags: python, import, module

I've a folder structure like this :

```
-PCore
    |-__init__.py
    |-PFnTransform.py
    |-PEuler.py
    |-PPoint3.py
    |-...
```

In each .py file there is a class with the same name.

And i just want to import by writting:

```
from Core import PPoint3
```

but actually I need to write:

```
from Core.PPoint3 import PPoint3
```

And when I print the class I got `<class 'PCore.PEuler.PEuler'>` instead of `<class 'PCore.PEuler'>` (what i want)

What I need to write in the `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: Is there a reason for putting each class in a separate file? You could put them all in `PCore.py` and selectively import them with `from PCore import PEuler, PPoint3`, without having to worry about the more complicated package structure involving `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers ! The only reason I do this way, it's to keep everything clean, I don't like python files with 5000 lines ...

Comment: [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names): Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names...

Answer (score 2):

In the `__init__.py` file, you need to import the `PPoint3` class.

```
from PPoint3 import PPoint3
```

Then, you'll be able to import the `PPoint3` class from the `PCore` package.